# NtGetContextThread invalid parameter

Tags: c, reverse-engineering

```
CONTEXT ctx;
NTSTATUS result = NtGetContextThread(hThread, &ctx);
```

`result` is fiiled with `0xC000000D`, which means `An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function.`

Now, I checked in several sources and they all say that you need: thread handle and a pointer to context structure.

I'm not sure where the problem is...

Comment: you not initialize `ctx` - *The value of the ctx.ContextFlags member of this structure specifies which portions of a thread's context are retrieved.*

Comment: If your intention by initialize is memory allocation - I assumed (probably incorrectly) that declaring a structure is enough. I also tried `PCONTEXT pctx = malloc(sizeof(CONTEXT));` and it didn't work. If it's *not* memory allocation, but something else, please tell.

Comment: but i tell - *The value of the `ContextFlags` member of this structure specifies which portions of a thread's context are retrieved* - what is unclear here ?

Comment: It's not that obvious. I'm trying to use initalizeContext now, i'll how it goes...

Comment: in this case can not help more, if not obvious that you need use `ctx.ContextFlags = xxx` before call `NtGetContextThread` all is documented - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreadcontext

Comment: Oh now I get you. My bad.